# Css grid: how to make cell adjust in width?

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid

I am using CSS grid display to layout a grid of items (can be cards, text, iframes, etc.) on the page, however sometimes an item in that list might be wider than the others, therefore overflow occurs. How may I fix this? I've noticed that in terms of height, columns actually adjust when there is more content without any problems with my current setup.

```
.wrapper-content {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill, minmax(11rem, auto));
 grid-auto-rows: minmax(12rem, auto);
 grid-gap: 1em;
}
```

Here's the problem, as you can see, an iframe is larger than the cards surrounding it and therefore it is covered.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually figured out how to achieve what I was looking for. We can set how many columns an item should span for. So for example if we have an iframe in a grid, perhaps we want it to span for 2 columns oppose to everything else spanning one column. To achieve that, we can create a class like so and then apply this class for iframe element:

```
.iframe-in-grid {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

If you want to make element bigger in terms of height, span it through rows like so:

```
grid-row: span 2;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set `max-width` for your images. Here is the code:

```
.wrapper-content img { max-width:100%}
```

If you are using a responsive layout, it is a must for your stylesheet file.

for the iframe or any other elements you need to change the grid system you can keep items next to each other with their original width by using this code:

```
.wrapper-content {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

or use flex `.wrapper-content {display:inline-flex}`

Also you can change the value of `grid-template-columns` property to auto so the size of the columns is determined by the size of the container and on the size of the content of the items in the column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, the problem is not with an image. That is an iframe that's getting out of it's cell size. And I don't want to limit it to the cell size, I want it to expand so it is shown properly without any coverage.

Comment: I edited my answer please take a look to see it works for you or not.

Comment: Hmm, well you see, the grid is working perfectly for the other elements so I wouldn't want to swap it for something else. Your proposed answer suggests to use a different display style for the wrapper class. But that would affect all of the elements, I can't apply it to just the ones that are out of bounds, can I? When I'm giving this a second thought, I'm starting to assume that actually what I want to achieve is not do-able with grid?

Comment: why don't you use `grid-template-columns: auto` ? now the size of the columns is determined by the size of the container and on the size of the content of the items in the column.

Comment: If I use `grid-template-columns: auto` I get only one column, spanning for whole width of the content area. I need multiple columns

Comment: I think the only way you can change a column width is to define a class for each column that you need to change its width and use something like this ` grid-column: auto / span 2;` you cannot use auto for minmax